# Pass Path From c# to matlab

Tags: c#, matlab, path, send

Matlab ,C# Expert 
I am trying to pass Path generated from c#

```
 (appPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
```

To dll created Script in matlab that contains functions

It Works when i send  Numeric ,string Values to the functions , let's say Function A 
but never works when I try to send paths

Looks like the `cd(path)` in the matlab function , does not work !

The thing is I have only One created dll function that the `cd(path)` work with it 
even though i created the same Mwarray version , the same matlab version ! 
I am confused 
i tried to send as Mwarray , Mwcell Char 
nothing Worked

I have no Idea what to do !

Answer (score 0):

It Looks like Matlab does not get the path correctly or even does not execute the `cd(path)` in correct way

Anyway Instead of change the Matlab path , you could access the directory of the desired folder

Here is how

```
fopen(fullfile(path,filenam));
```

That is how I solved My issue

Best Regard